# Emberjs: Self-referencing relationship not loading children when in a controller variable

Tags: javascript, ember.js

I am having an issue with nested components and there data.

I have a couple models like the following:

Category:

```
App.Category = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    ...,
    choices: DS.hasMany('categoryChoices')
});
```

CategoryChoice:

```
App.CategoryChoices = DS.Model.extend({
    name: DS.attr('string'),
    ...,
    children: DS.hasMany('categoryChoices')
});
```

Then I have a view template like this:

```
<div>
{{#each category}}
    {{category-selector category=this}}
{{/each}}
</div>
```

Now the component templates:

Category Selector:

```
<div class='header'>
    {{category.name}}
</div>
<div class='choices'>
    {{#each category.choices}}
        {{category-choice-selector choice=this}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

Category Choice Selector:

```
<div>
    {{choice.name}}
</div>
<div class='children'>
    {{#each choice.children}}         
        {{category-choice-selector choice=this}}
    {{/each}}
</div>
```

This is just a rough example, but the problem is that the children of the choices never get loaded. So if I have a category like the following:

- Food

  - Meat

    - Steak
    - Chicken
  - Fruit

    - Pear
    - Apple

The choices under Meat and Fruit never appear. Not sure what I am doing wrong here.